# Bootstrap 4 not displaying the classes properly in Chrome

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm new to frontend so the solution might be really simple.

This is an Angular 7 project.

I am following a youtube guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZbZ5AHZJnc&t=1s) on how to use bootstrap with Angular and the only difference is that he is using bootstrap 3 and I am using bootstrap 4, but I changed to his version(3.3.7) and I'm getting the same output in chrome.

I didn't use npm to install bootstrap because from what I understood you either put those scripts in the head and body or use npm install but not both. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ChatAppUI</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h2>Angular & Bootstrap demo</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Status
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**This is what I am expecting:**
[image]

**This is what I get in chrome using Bootstrap 3.3.7:**
[image]

**This is what I get using Bootstrap 4.4.1:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Classes in Bootstrap 3 and 4 are sometimes different. As I see you are using panels. [Panels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#panels) are removed and replaced with card class. Have a look in [this doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/) to see migration between BS3 and BS4.

Also: Are you including stylesheet to v3? As I see in your code you are only linking to v4.

Comment: so you are saying I can put all these lines of code in my index.html and than I can use ,for example, card and panels and they will both work ?<br/>`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"...>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="...">`<br/>`<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"...></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"...></script>`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. If you want to use BS4 use BS4 only. I though you want to test BS3 (don't include BS3 CSS tho). In this case change panels to cards and other classes according to above doc.